# How small can you slice a HTML5 Canvas pixel?

Tags: html, canvas

In Flash, pixels are calculated using twips, or twentieth of a pixel. Consequently, every position is always in multiples of 0.05. I haven't seen this mentioned in the HTML Canvas spec and am unable to trace the cursor position on Canvas. Does anyone know the accuracy of its pixel calculations?

**Edit for clarification:**

I'm referring more to [Zeno's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes) which says in order to move something from point A to point B, it must first move to a point halfway between the two. And then halfway again, ad infinitum.

So if I want to move on the x axis from point 0 to 100 at 0.5:

1. At frame 1: 50
2. Frame 2: 75
3. Frame 3: 87.5
4. Then: 93.75, 96.875, 98.4375... etc.

So at what step does the Canvas actually round-up to the next pixel?

Comment: Not sure specifically about the canvas, but Chrome's implementation of CSS has never liked size values containing decimal places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean by accuracy of slicing.

Pixels on the Canvas can be drawn to a little less than 0.10, after which they make barely any visible impact.

Of course, if you scale, you can draw things that are 0.00125 pixels, and so on. But they won't be visible if you unscale.

http://jsfiddle.net/GvVD9/

(That first square block on the top-left is a pixel)

Accuracy of the **mouse** is an entirely different thing, in no way related to the canvas spec.

EDIT:

Well, we can sorta demonstrate that. We can draw a bunch of pixels with y values approaching 100 and see how they compare to a red pixel drawn with the y value 100.

http://jsfiddle.net/GvVD9/46/

Every single horizontally separated piece is just a single 1 by 1 pixel rect using the drawRect command.

```
50
75
87.5
93.75  // first black pixel you see in image
96.875
98.4375
99.21875
99.609375
99.8046875
99.90234375
99.951171875
99.9755859375
99.98779296875
99.993896484375
99.9969482421875 // last black pixel you see in image
```

[image]

Comment: Nice little demo.  I am educated.

Comment: Thanks, your code cleared some things up. From what I can gather, there is no limit in Canvas, rather, it's UA-defined. This allows browsers to have a high-res backing store if they'd like.

Comment: Correct, which means you can write paths/text in an SVG-like manner and expect very accurate representation when scaled to large values. Some of the implementation of the above is different across browser though (anti-aliasing or not isn't a choice you get, it is a choice the browser makes unfortuantely. Also, scaled + rotated text is broken in some browsers [Chrome, opera])